# NFS permissions (with AKS)

Tags: linux, nfs, kubernetes

I'm mounting NFS (on the Azure Virtual Machine) into k8s (AKS). My application is running with Apache (www-data user). Now for some reason I cannot eventually comprehend my application errors with permission denied error, namely it cannot write into mounted NFS volume. It is clearly permissions issue and also I messed it all up together.

Application run by Apache: `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)` Exported from NFS directory and all its children (recursively): I've chowned them to `www-data:www-data`.

When I type id in the container I'm root: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1000` When I touch new file in the container in the mounted volume it has permissions: `uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)`. It is a bit surprising.

When I type id in the NFS server: `uid=1000(azureuser) gid=1000(azureuser) groups=1000(azureuser)` If I touch new file in NFS server it has: `uid=1000(azureuser) gid=1000(azureuser) groups=1000(azureuser)`. So this I assume is connected with this declaration in deployment k8s config:

```
securityContext:
 fsGroup: 1000
```

`/etc/exports` file in the NFS I configured like so:
`/export 10.240.0.0/16(rw,async,insecure,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)`

I'm confused what is what now, could you help me solving this and clarify what is what?

Btw the connection between NFS and AKS is established (I can create a file in the container in the mounted volume and it will be visible in the NFS server, also opposite works).

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: Could you please share a example pod definition with NFS volume + securityContext that you are using? How did you configure NFS server on VM? Could you please share steps / tutorial that you followed?

Comment: Hello @Murakami. Any updates?